# Can I use hlookup or something similar to keep looking for specific text?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So here's what I'm trying to do.

Here is a mock-up for example's sake of what I'm trying to get a function for.

[image]

On the left I have people in columns (B/C) and food in rows (2/3).
Where the person and food meet in the table, I want to search the data on the right to see if their name appears underneath that food's text.
With the data I gave, ALL of the boxes should have Xs in them, because both Kari and Hope are below Pizza AND Hotdog in the table.
However, `HLookUp` only displays the first result (or last if I change it to approximate match).
What can I do to make it check every result and then display an X if ANY of the results match?

Here is the formula I'm using so far:

```
=IFERROR(IF(HLOOKUP($A2,$E$1:$G$2,2,false)=B$1,"X",""),"")
```

`IFERROR`, so that I can keep the cell empty if it doesn't find any matches.
`IF`, if true, X. If false, blank.
`HLOOKUP`, look for the food, then get the cell below it.

The problem being, as I said, once it finds the first result for "Pizza" it's going to check below  that and see that it's Hope. Is there a way, or a different function I can use, to make it so that it keeps looking until it finds Pizza with Kari under it?

I have a sheet with similar data. The data is always a specific item, then a name underneath it. I just want to display an X in the other table if there is EVER a combination of that item and their name. I'm new to excel so figuring this out has been difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `COUNTIFS()` in `B2`:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($E$1:$H$1,$A2,$E$2:$H$2,B$1),"X","")
```

Drag down and right.

Answer (score 0):

Not the output as you stated it to be, but I think this may be very useful for you.

If in `E1` you type `=B1`
In `E2` you type `=IFERROR(FILTER($A:$A,B:B="x"),"none")`

The result will be the name of the first person in your list and a summary of the choices this person made (multiple choices are possible), or shows `none` if nothing's selected.

You can drag cells `E1` & `E2` to the right to get the results for other persons:
[image: example_1]

You can also have it the other way around:
Put the following formula in `E1`:
`=INDIRECT("A"&COLUMNS($A1:B1))`
That's for the food header.

In `E2` use the following formula:
`=IFERROR(TRANSPOSE(FILTER($B$1:$D$3,INDIRECT("B"&MATCH(E$1,$A$1:$A4,0)&":C"&MATCH(E$1,$A$1:$A4,0))="x")),"none")`

The result will be the name of the first food in your list and a summary of the persons who chose this (multiple choices are possible), or it shows `none` if nobody selected the food.

You can drag cells `E1` & `E2` to the right to get the results for other food:
[image: example_2]

Both are not the output as you proposed, but I think this may be more helpful in giving better oversight over the choices.